# Error sending some unsigned int through serial port (teensy -> raspi)

Tags: linux, usb, teensy

I am encountering some troubles trying to communicate through USB between a teensy and a Raspberry Pi3.

When I send unsigned int, I receive wrong numbers for all the numbers containing the byte of value 13 which is changed to the value 10

For example :

```
13 becomes 10;
269 becomes 266;
525 becomes 522;
781 becomes 778;
1037 1034;
1293 1290; 
1549 1546; 
1805 1802; 
etc...
```

but not for the others...

Whatever if I use my program on the pi or if I send a cat command over `/dev/ttyACMO`. However, when I do the same on another computer, everything works fine.

I got the same problem on another computer so I think the problem come from a bad library I have installed.

Do you have any idea?

PS: the code on the teensy is as simple as :

```
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(true){
        Serial.write((char*) &i, 4);
        ++i;
        delay(500);
    }
```

Comment: problem solved : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209980/serial-port-binary-transfer-changes-carriage-return thank you !

Answer (score 1):

ASCII decimal 10 is **line feed**  (`<LF>`). ASCII decimal 13 is **carrige return**  (`<LF>`).

You're most likely victium of implicit `<CR><LF>` ⇄ `<LF>` conversion; [Wikipedia explains it in detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Issues_with_different_newline_formats) but in summary it's rooted in technological history:

- When computers were given text input/output capabilities for the first time, this was not done through displays, but teletypes. A teletype is essentially a mechanical typewriter, where each "key" can be hit also by an electrical signal.
- Typewriters, and thereby teletypes distinguished between **advancing the paper a line** (line feed), and **returning the carrige** (the typing head) back to the start of a line.
- The ASCII encoding was created as essentially a 1:1 mapping of the functions of a typewriter to binary patterns.

The net effect was, that in order to start a new line on a teletype you'd have to send a **line feed** (`<LF>`) together with a **carrige return** (`<CR>`), the order of the two doesn't exactly matter, the physical effect is practically the same.

However different operating systems settled on different *default* conventions how to store and transmit newlines:

- MS-DOS and by inheritance Windows chose to explicitly store both `<CR>` and `<LF>` in that order.
- Unix chose to store the `<LF>` only and translate it into a `<CR><LF>` sequence when sending it to a teletype, and do it vice-versa on reception. Linux adopted this Unix convention.

When it comes to the transmission over a serial link, the default however always has been, that for a newline a `(<CR>,<LF>)` pair should be transmitted, in expectation of the other end being a teletype. *And this is, what's likely going on here! The actual data transmitted over the wire is a `<CR><LF>` but the receiving OS having inherited the ways of Unix silently converts it into a plain `<LF>`.* And for any number bigger than 255 this conversion will happen to its lower 8 byte, together with dropping a whole byte.

Of course this default behavior can be reconfigured, namely through [termios/ioctl_tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) on the opened serial port, specifically the output and input option flags (namely the flags `OPOST`, `ONLCR`, `ONLCR`, `OCRNL`, `ONLRET`, `INLCR`, `IGNCR`, `ICRNL`).

However I strongly suggest you don't fiddle with these flags and instead take the following two lessions to heart:

- **Plain text is the universal exchange format!** *(i.e. don't submit raw binary over a wire, if you can avoid it, but send it as – also human readable – text)*
- **Be liberal in reading what you receive; be conservative in what you send!** *(i.e. write your program in a way, that reading data is not dependent on a strict order and format of the data, i.e. may tolerate any kind of newline sequence or number of whitespace delimiting field; but also send data in a strict regular way so that less liberal receivers don't choke on it)*