# What could be the difference between an embedded serial read operation and a Desktop- PC

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux, uart

In an embedded Linux system, I am coding the project which tests serial port in a pyhsically loopback environment. It means I am connecting rx-tx.The peripheral output is RS-232

In order to test the port I am sending 1 byte then I read the sent byte. I repeat this cycle from 0x00 to 0XFF. I am using raw input type for UART.

It looks fine if I run my code on Linux-desktop PC.

However on my embedded Linux system, I can not read from RS-232 connection properly. At the end, I got read return zero.

What do you think about the possible problem?

I am checking my termios configuration referenced to the [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#CONTENTS)

```
         StatusResult  UartInterface::openComPort() {

           m_fileDesc = open(m_device.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );

            if (m_fileDesc == -1) {
                retStatus.type = COMM_ERROR;
            }
            configureUART();
            return retStatus;
        }


        void UartInterface::configureUART(){

                struct termios options;

                tcgetattr(m_fileDesc, &options);

                cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
                cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);

                options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL |CREAD);

                tcsetattr(m_fileDesc, TCSANOW, &options);

                options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
                options.c_cflag |= CS8;
                options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
                options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
                options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
                /*=============================================*/

                options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

                /*=============================================*/

                options.c_iflag &= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

                /*=============================================*/

                options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

                /*=============================================*/

                options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
                options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

                tcsetattr(m_fileDesc, TCSANOW, &options);

            }
```

Here is my main test loop

```
    std::cout<<"-----------UART DEBUG-------------\n";


    while( int(write_data) < 255 ){
        n = write(m_fileDesc, &write_data, 1);
        if( n != 1) {
            std::cout << "UART write failed!\n";
            res=false;
            return res;
        }

        n = read(m_fileDesc, &read_data, 1);
        if ( n == 1){
            if(read_data != write_data) {
                std::cout << "UART mismatch error!\t data_read:0x" << int(read_data)<<"   data write:0x"<<int(write_data)<< std::endl;
                res=false;
                //return res;
            }

            std::cout<<std::hex<<"Byte: 0x"<<int(read_data) <<"  is OK!"<<std::endl;


        }
        else {
            std::cout << "UART read failed! Res: "<<n<<"Errno"<< strerror(errno)<<std::endl;
            res=false;
            return res;
        }
        write_data++;
    }
    (res) ? (std::cout<<"Uart interface test OK!"<<std::endl) : ((std::cout<<"UART FAILED!!"<<std::endl));
    return res;
}
```

Here is the output for embedded linux system.As you see read and write data are completely different. After an amount of repetation it ends with zero read?

```
    -----------UART DEBUG-------------
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x1
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x2
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x3
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x4
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x5
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x6
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x7
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x8
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x0   data write:0x9
Byte: 0x0  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x1   data write:0xa
Byte: 0x1  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x2   data write:0xb
Byte: 0x2  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x3   data write:0xc
Byte: 0x3  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x4   data write:0xd
Byte: 0x4  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x5   data write:0xe
Byte: 0x5  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x6   data write:0xf
Byte: 0x6  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x7   data write:0x10
Byte: 0x7  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x8   data write:0x11
Byte: 0x8  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x9   data write:0x12
Byte: 0x9  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0xa   data write:0x13
Byte: 0xa  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0xb   data write:0x14
Byte: 0xb  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0xc   data write:0x15
Byte: 0xc  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0xd   data write:0x16
Byte: 0xd  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0xe   data write:0x17
Byte: 0xe  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0xf   data write:0x18
Byte: 0xf  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x10   data write:0x19
Byte: 0x10  is OK!
UART mismatch error!     data_read:0x12   data write:0x1a
Byte: 0x12  is OK!
UART read failed! Res: 0 Errno: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete. It doesn't show how you open the UART device. When `read` or `write` fails you should print its return value and if negative also print the error message corresponding to the `errno` value.

Comment: With (desktop and/or embedded)  Linux your application does not have access to the *"uart port"*. Rather you are reading from a serial terminal, which is denoted by the device name `/dev/tty...`. Your application is several layers removed from the *"uart port"*. See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).  *"What do you think about the possible problem?"* -- Incomplete or improper termios initialization.

Comment: @Bodo I have added termios configuration and return value.

Comment: @sawdust I read your older discussions about similar topic. I am checking termios configuration again but if you see sth wrong about configuration please inform me. Actually I am suspicious that read and write cycles were too close for an embedded system. But according to Bodo's and your advice I focus on termios configuration again.

Comment: You did not yet show the `open` call for `m_fileDesc`. What did you change in the code that results in `UART mismatch error!` which you did not have before? Does `UART read failed! Res: 0`... show the value of `n`? This would mean "no data available" or something EOF/"connection closed". I don't know why you read `0x0` several times, but there seems to be some delay in the UART driver or hardware. Do you use non-blocking mode for the file descriptor? This looks suspicious: `options.c_iflag &= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);` You switch off three flags and leave all others as they were. Is this OK?

Comment: @Bodo Added open port method. I only changed logging style.I already got mismatch error before. But I get read return zero when the data come to CR (0x13) It looks it is misconfigured as a raw input mode isn't it?

Comment: Maybe there is some option active that removes CR or translates CR+LF to LF. Return value 0 from `read` seems to mean "no data available" I don't know why the `read` does not block. BTW: in `UartInterface::openComPort` you should not call `configureUART();` if `(m_fileDesc == -1)`.

Comment: You still have not provided a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.  As you post more code, you are obviously also changing that code, such that the results are totally different!  Your problem is a moving target.  The original issue was certainly a SW flow-control misconfiguration.  The new output you post does not match the code.  Where does the *"Res: 0 Errno:..."* output come from in your code?  Why isn't there an `else` between `if(read_data != write_data) { ... }` and `std::cout<<std::hex<<"Byte: 0x"...`?  Why aren't you testing the return code from all syscalls, e.g. tcsetattr()?

Comment: An old convention is to perform a **tcflush()** after a **tcsetattr()**, especially when changing the baudrate and/or line settings.  A **tcflush()** would probably get rid of the initial garbage data you seem to be reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with 3 corrections:

First, I found a mistake about termios configuration. Here my hw. flow control must be closed and a Tildy looks missing.

```
 options.c_iflag &= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); //FALSE
 options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); //CORRECT
```

After all, it figured out read return with zero problem. I can complete my test data up to 255. However, read and write data still mismatch!

Second I cleared all the termios flags instead of reading from the system.This provides me independency from the operating environment.

Then I added the following 2 lines after tcsetattr() in order to flush first data. And sleep() is necessary because the ioctl syscall can't find any data to flush unless you wait for a while.

```
 ....
//tcgettattr(m_fileDesc, &options); //Ignore default system data
memset(&options, 0, sizeof options);
.
.
tcsetattr(m_fileDesc, TCSANOW, &options);
sleep(2);
tcflush(m_fileDesc, TCIOFLUSH);
```

sleep() looks like a workaround but I couldn't find a better solution. Additionally, the following topics are very helpful.
[Clearing the serial port's buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013387/clearing-the-serial-ports-buffer)

[Serial port binary transfer changes carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209980/serial-port-binary-transfer-changes-carriage-return)

Comment: If you want to be sure about the settings you should set or clear all flags because the old settings (or the default) may be different on different platforms. `IXON` etc are for software flow control, hardware flow control is `CRTSCTS`. See also my comment below the question.

Comment: Please edit your original question to update it with this information, since this isn't an answer (you're still having issues and still have questions).

Comment: @David Makogon I have solved the problem and uptaded the answer.

Comment: *"Second I cleared all the termios flags instead of reading from the system."* -- That's an inferior solution that is not portable, and may not always work.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)